# Iterate integration and plot result in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to iterate a numeric integration in scipy and plot the result. However it returns an error that 'float' object is not iterable. What is the correct way to to this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def g(x):
    if (np.abs(x)<1e-10):
        res = x
    else:
        res = x*np.sin(1.0/x)
    return res

X = np.arange(-0.5,0.5,0.001)

#plot(X,f(X))

def f(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(g,0,val)
        res[i]=y
    return res


def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(f,0,val)
        res[i]=y
    return res

plt.plot(X,F(X))
```

(The code is based on this answer: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21871/11911)

Comment: There is not a computational science issue here, it's a straightforward programming error, so I voted to close this as off-topic. I think you are passing $f$ to `quad`, and `quad` calls it with a float argument, but $f$ then tries to `enumerate` that float argument, leading to the error. This is not the right place to ask people to debug your code for you (see the help centre and the meta).

Comment: Hm. Thanks but I don't see, how to fix it. Do you think it might be more appropriate on stackoverflow.sx?

Comment: @student yes, you can flag for moderator intervention and ask to migrate to SO